# How I do javascript string manipulation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable like this:

```
var data= [{"Timestamp":1349816400000,"TaskEffortLeft":123},{"Timestamp":1352498400000,"TaskEffortLeft":-123}]
```

Now I want to strip out those "Timestamp": and "TaskEffortLeft": and also change curly brackets into big bracket and make it Like this:

```
var data= [[1349816400000,123],[1352498400000,-123]]
```

How do I do that?
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var result = data.map(function(item) {
   return [item.Timestamp, item.TaskEffortLeft];
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am not into javascrpt so much. That's why I asked this question which may look like stupid to pros. But you are great unlike others above.

Comment: No problem. Sorry to say but those guys are kinda right. You need to read some books.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var arr = [];
​$.each(data, function(){
    var temp = [];
    temp.push(data["Timestamp"] );
    temp.push(data["TaskEffortLeft"] );
    arr.push(temp)
});
console.log(arr)
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/7sBcA/)**
    ​